# titles without enumerate

Tags: titles, enumerate

I have multiple paragraphs, each with a different title. I'm using letters `(A,B,C,...)` to go along with the titles, for example:

A. title-1 (I want this in italic)

body text

B. title-2

body text

and so on...I tried using enumerate as follows:

```
\begin{enumerate}[{\em A.}]
\item{\em title-1}  
body text

\item{\em title-2}
body text
\end{enumerate}
```

However the indentation of the text is different from the other paragraphs I have just before this part. I'd be grateful if someone can show a better way of doing this.

Comment: Use `\paragraph{title}` and customize its appearance with the `titlesec` package.

Comment: @SeanAllred Does this generate the letters (A,B,C,...) automatically without me having to write them explicitly.

Answer (score 7):

Implementing Sean's suggestion. The following document uses the `titlesec` package to format the `\paragraph` command so that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{chngcntr} % for easy manipulation of counters
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for dummy text
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % make sure paragraphs will be numbered
% set up the format for the paragraph
\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\normalfont}{\theparagraph.}{.5em}{\emph}
% make the paragraph counter reset every section
\counterwithin{paragraph}{section}
% define the display of the counter to be upper case alpha
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\Alph{paragraph}}
\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\paragraph{A paragraph}
\kant[1]
\paragraph{Another paragraph}
\kant[2]
\section{Another section}
\paragraph{Another paragraph}
\kant[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you, I get an error when I use \usepackage{titlesec}, but I'm sure that's just an issue with my latex installtion.

Comment: @SoCal93 The `titlesec` package should be part of any installation, I think. Are you using TeX Live or MikTeX?

Comment: I'm using MikeTex. 'titlesec.sty' is missing, I tried installing it, but I get "undefined control sequence".

Comment: "undefined control sequence" is not the error you get when a package is missing.  Are you trying to compile my sample document?

Comment: Your code compiles perfectly, but when I include it in my file, I get all kinds of errors.

Comment: Ok. So this has nothing to do with your installation, but with your actual document. When you get an "undefined control sequence" it's usually from a typo or from a missing `\usepackage` command for the style file that defines that macro. The line immediately after the error should show which macro TeX didn't recognize, and give you a line number.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9431/discussion-between-alan-munn-and-socal93)

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own command with your own formatting.  For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{paracnt}
\newcommand{\para}[1]{\par\refstepcounter{paracnt}\Alph{paracnt}.
  \textit{#1.} }
\begin{document}

\para{Title-1}  First

\para{Title-2}  Second

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this will work with `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: OP did not ask his titles to be in TOC.

Comment: @Boris Thank you. Anyway I can extend this to have the letters start over from A for each new section.